# AWS PHp Configurations

Tags: php, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have installed PHP on EC2 AWS, Earlier, it was printing the PHP tags instead of executing it.

Now, PHP files are being downloaded instead of being executed.

Any idea why is this happeining?

I have checked Apache is installed on server.

I tried running the following command

```
sudo yum install httpd24 php56 mysql55-server php56-mysqlnd
```

It shows

```
No Package httpd24 available
No Package php56 available
```

I tried

```
sudo yum update -y
```

It shows loaded plugins langpacks, priorties, update-mod
no package moared for update.

What  am i missing ?

Comment: Which AMI are you using? Do you want PHP 5.6, or a different version? But look at your error, it didn't install PHP, so that's (one of the reasons) why your code is being displayed and not executed.

Comment: Also, you mention that you checked that Apache is installed on the server, how did you verify this? It also appears to not have installed.

Comment: amzn2-ami-hvm-2017.12.0.20180115-x86_64-gp2

Answer (score 0):

Did you install php as well? 
Depending on your server OS, and the desired PHP version:

If you need you need PHP 7, you need to install epel release
Then install PHP